# Finding a polynomial that satisfies a certain composition of functions

Tags: polynomials, function-and-relation-composition

Find all polynomials P(X) such that P(P(X)) = X. Then find all polynomials P(X) such that P(P(P(X)))= X.

Pretty much stuck, I have no experience with polynomials and the only thing I think that can help me is derivatives and the chain rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $P$ has degree $2$ or more, then $P(P(x))$ will have higher degree, so we may rule that out. If $P$ is constant, then clearly $P(P(x)) \ne x$. So we are relegated to the case that $P$ is linear, so that $P(x) = ax + b$. We then find that

$$x = P(ax + b) = a(ax + b) + b = a^2 x + ab + b$$

This gives us conditions on $a$ and $b$ that we can use to narrow it down even further.

---

For an approach using calculus as you mentioned, note that

$$1 = (P(P(x))' = P'(P(x)) P'(x)$$

In particular, we see that $P'$ must be constant, verifying that $P$ can only be linear.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I see it. So P is linear in both, it's just setting bounds on the constants that needs to be tampered with?

Comment: @TimG Yes. Just getting that $P$ is linear narrows it down a lot, but it doesn't tell us about constants.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the right thing to do, but I tried figuring out x in terms of a and b and got that a cannot be -1 or 1, and b can range. Somehow I don't think this is right... I tried the calculus method and got that by the derivative $a^2 x + b$ = 1

Comment: @TimG Not quite. Recall that two polynomials are equal if and only if their coefficients are equal. The coefficient of $x$ on the right is $a^2$, and on the left, it's $1$; so $a = $? Likewise for the constant term.

Comment: So a can be -1 or 1, while b has to be 0. For the second problem, a can only be 1, and b must be 0. I think that is the solution.

Answer (score 3):

If $P(X)$ has degree $n$, then $P(P(X))$ has degree $n^2$. Do you see how this helps you?